# What are your 'best practices' for writing custom controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have started writing some custom controls for a highly visual project. I was wondering what are your 'best practices' when coding WPF custom controls?

Comment: You should ask for one tip/recommendation per answer on questions like this for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the control can be re-styled and re-templated without changing the way the control operates. Don't make the control assume that the Listbox and Button are both within the same panel or that there even is a Listbox or Button. Check out the [MSDN article on control authoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx) for some recommendations on how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your custom control to support direct content like this:

```
<CustomObject>
    Direct content example 1
</CustomObject>

<!-- or -->

<CustomObject>
    <Button Content="Direct content example 2" />
</CustomObject>
```

Then you need to use the `ContentPropertyAttribute` which tells WPF which property is actually being set when you write xaml like this.

The attribute can be used like this:

```
[ContentProperty("NameOfProperty")]
public class CustomObject
{
    [...]
```

`ContentControl` uses this attribute to set the Content property but note that the property can be called anything; the WPF `TextBox`, for example uses this attribute to set the `Text` property.

E.G.

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
```

The property also does *not* have to be a dependency property (see the MSDN documentation example for evidence of this).

Finally, this attribute is specific to the xaml parser and not to `ContentControl` and can be used with any type which can be seen from the `TextBox` example above (`TextBox` does not derive from `ContentControl`).

Answer (score 3):

Keep property names the same as the property names for built-in Controls if you can do so without changing their meaning.

e.g. if you have a CustomerDisplayer custom control don't call the list of customers Customers, call it ItemsSource.

It might seem counter intuitive at first but it saves a lot of headache in the long run because future programmers can make a lot of assumptions about how a property called ItemsSource will act that they can't necessarily make about a Customers property.

Answer (score 1):

Some content controls are dependant on the existence of other controls in their `ControlTemplate`. Typically this should be documented using the `TemplatePart` attribute.

The `Combobox` control, for example, is dependant on the existence of a `TextBox` and a `Popup` controls in its template.

This would be documented by placing the attribute on the class like so:

```
[TemplatePart(name="PART_EditableTextBox", type=typeof(TextBox))]
[TemplatePart(name="PART_Popup", type=typeof(Popup))]
public class Combobox : Selector
{
    [...]
```

The naming convention is "PART_controlIdentifier".

The relevant items would then be given the same names in the control template so that they can be located in the `OnApplyTemplate` method.

This then allows the control to hook up to events, set properties and call methods on the controls contained in the template.

This attribute is for documentation purposes so that people designing custom control templates (and tools such as Expression Blend) know that the control is dependant on the existence of another.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use both [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) and [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) (and how they work) so that you can use them effectively in your own control.

Both of these types provide services for integrating your control with the systems built into WPF.

By using these two features in your custom controls you will get the following advantages:

1. Dependency Properties provide support for databinding, animations and can be used in styles.
2. Routed Events can be propogated through the visual tree which means that other elements can handle the events.